# What to do when a scatter plot doesn't appear to plot all data?

Tags: data-visualization, pandas, matplotlib

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'input': [3009861162, 548584145, 950178496, 984257236, 447403092, 447403094, 445305942, 445306198, \
                         2592658903, 2592921015, 2592920999], 'output': [2917869018, 622408909, 621393093, 749384917, \
782939349, 2930425029, 2930425313, 2930425249, 2393546529, 2527846001, 3601419873]})

plt.scatter(df['input'], df['output'], s=0.5)
plt.show()
```

[image]

It doesn't *look* like all the points are plotted.  I believe that is because some numbers are numerically close to one another and are being overplotted.  What are good ways to visualize such bivariate data in a scatterplot-like manner?

Comment: Are you sure they're not plotted? They are more likely overlapped. You can try plotting each point different colours then reverse the direction of the vectors, see if the colour on top changes.

Comment: You can try adding "plt.title('There should be ' + str(len(df['input'])) + ' dots')" and manually counting as a quick check when the number of data points is few.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In R, you can add some random noise to each plotted point (and make points "hollow") to make them a bit more visible while plotting.  For example:

```
plot(input, output, col="red")
```

yields:

[image]

but

```
plot(jitter(input, factor = 50, amount = NULL), jitter(output, factor = 50, amount = NULL))
```

yields:

[image]

You can adjust the parameters of jitter a bit to add more or less noise as you see fit.  I'd imagine there is a similar function in python or you could simply add some random noise to each point yourself.  See here for some examples in python:

https://scientificallysound.org/2017/08/17/jitter-to-figures-python-r/

Switching to a log scale with jitter might help too.  For example:

```
loginput<-log(input)
logoutput<-log(output)

plot(jitter(loginput, factor = 50, amount = NULL), 
         jitter(logoutput, factor = 50, amount = NULL), 
         col="blue", xlab="log input", ylab="log output")
```

results in:

[image]